# How can I access files without mapping a drive through net use?

Tags: powershell

I want to access files from other domain, so I'm using this command:

```
net use n: \\10.0.0.1\share /user:domain\user password
```

but as I have to map this drive to `N:` and then use it.
Is there any way that I can directly use file without mapping.
Let suppose I want to use `get-content` to open a `.txt` file.

New to this so please provide me way.

Comment: I wonder if this is more related to [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/)...

Comment: Pay your attention to `-Credential` parameter of `get-content` (or other cmdlet).

Comment: Solution might differ depending on your version of Powershell. What version are you using?

Comment: powershell version is 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've had success accessing resources on a non-domain machine by using this variant of the NET command:

`net use \\nodename /user:.\username password`

The above is for a machine local account, replace the `.` with domain name for a domain account.

It establishes credentials to access the machine without mapping a drive.   After this, accessing files through powershell cmdlets using UNC naming should work.

Comment: Most any command, yes.   Technically it needs to support UNC style paths, but I can't think of any modern apps that don't.